# Вызов функции из командной строки

Tags: lisp

Например есть такая функция:

```
;                   N      D
Задание:« ?  ?(x+y)»
              x=1   y=1
(defun summa(n a)
    (if (= n 1)
        (sum n a)
        ( + (sum n a) (summa (- n 1) a))))
(defun sum(n a)
  (if (= a 1)
      (+ n a)
      ( + (+ n a) (sum n (- a 1)))))
```

Что нужно написать в командной строке для вызова например sum (4 4)?

Comment: я вызываю так (sum 4 4)
он пишет error: unbound function - SUM

Comment: ну дык сперва нужно код с функциями загрузить. Какой компилятор используете?

В sbcl например можно загрузить код и файла с помощью `(load "file.lisp")`

Comment: про загрузку не знала, теперь все норм, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(sum 4 4)`

Comment: А интересней вызвать (summa 4 4)